# MapServer Kerneldensity empty map

Tags: postgis, mapserver, heat-map

I'm trying generate a heatmap from my PostGIS table, but my map is empty...

Here is my config file:

```
LAYER
  NAME feature_heatmap
  TYPE raster
  CONNECTIONTYPE kerneldensity
  CONNECTION "point_data"
  STATUS ON

  PROCESSING "RANGE_COLORSPACE=HSL"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_RADIUS=50"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_COMPUTE_BORDERS=ON"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_NORMALIZATION=auto"
  OFFSITE 0 0 0

    CLASS
        STYLE
            COLORRANGE  "#0000FFFF"  "#FF0000FF"
            DATARANGE 0 255
        END
    END
 END
```

And my "point_data" layer:

```
layer
    name "point_data"
    status on
    processing "close_connection=defer"
    extent -180 -90 180 90
    projection
        "init=epsg:4326"
    end
    connectiontype postgis
    connection "MY CONNECTION STRING"
    data "geom from my_geom_table using unique id using srid=4326"
    type point
    metadata
        "ows_title" "feature_heatmap"
        "ows_abstract" "Test heatmap"
        "ows_srs" "epsg:4326"
        "ows_enable_request" "*"
        "wms_timeitem" "pass_time"
        "wms_timeextent" "2001-01-01/2018-12-31"
        "wms_timedefault" "2001-01-01"
    end
end
```

My result: 
[image]

Only "point_data" layer:

[image]

Comment: What is your MapServer version?

Comment: @user30184 Version is 7.0.7

Comment: i just enabled DEBUG and i'm getting: "no overlap ... no result"

Comment: How does the GetMap request look?

Comment: `https://MY_URL/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&layers=feature_heatmap&styles=&format=image%2Fpng&transparent=true&version=1.1.1&width=512&height=512&srs=EPSG%3A4326&bbox=-45,-40.979898069620134,-22.5,-21.94304553343818`

Comment: Do you have data there? The BBOX is about here https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=4/-40.00/-23.00

Comment: It's weird.. using another layer, i have data.. The LonLat bbox address is near to São Paulo - Brazil

Comment: Could you modify your point layer to use some public dataset, for example https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_populated_places_simple.zip? It would help others to help you.

Comment: Yes, i can.. i'll do it and answer you.. Just one more thing, the bbox is LONLAT, it's right?

Comment: With WMS version 1.1.1 and EPSG:4326 it is lon-lat.

Comment: @user30184, so, the boundbox it's right, not?

Comment: @user30184 i tried the public dataset.. same problem, apparently when i use WMS without mode=map the mapserver doesnt understand the data as 4326

Comment: Try to add PROJECTION block to your heatmap layer. There is a mapfile that used to work in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102563/heat-map-density-map-from-dynamic-points-table-in-mapserver-geoserver/102564#102564

Comment: @user30184 tried.. same result :/..

Answer (score 1):

Your mapfile works for me. I made some small changes and digitized a few points into a shapefile "heatmap_points.shp" as test data.

This is my mapfile

```
MAP
  NAME ""
  STATUS ON
MAXSIZE 5000  
CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "c:\ms4w\apps\heatmap_error.txt"
CONFIG "CPL_DEBUG" "ON"
EXTENT -180 -90 180 90
  SIZE 600 600 
  SHAPEPATH "c:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp"
  IMAGECOLOR 255 255 255
  UNITS METERS
  WEB
    IMAGEPATH "c:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp"
    IMAGEURL "c:/ms4w/tmp/ms_tmp"
      METADATA
      "ows_enable_request" "*"      
      "wms_srs"    "EPSG:4326"
      "wms_onlineresource"    "http://localhost:80/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=c:/ms4w/apps/heatmap.map"
      "wms_title"    "heatmaptest"
     END
  END
    PROJECTION
    "init=epsg:4326" 
  END
  DEBUG OFF


  LAYER
  NAME feature_heatmap
  TYPE raster
  CONNECTIONTYPE kerneldensity
  CONNECTION "point_data"
  STATUS ON

  PROCESSING "RANGE_COLORSPACE=HSL"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_RADIUS=50"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_COMPUTE_BORDERS=ON"
  PROCESSING "KERNELDENSITY_NORMALIZATION=auto"
  OFFSITE 0 0 0

    CLASS
        STYLE
            COLORRANGE  "#0000FFFF"  "#FF0000FF"
            DATARANGE 0 255
        END
    END
 END

layer
    name "point_data"
    status on
    extent -180 -90 180 90
    projection
        "init=epsg:4326"
    end
    data heatmap_points
    type point
    metadata
        "ows_title" "heatmap_points"
        "ows_abstract" "Test heatmap"
        "ows_srs" "epsg:4326"
        "ows_enable_request" "*"
    end
end   

END
```

This is my WMS GetMap request:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?
map=c:\ms4w\apps\heatmap.map&
REQUEST=GetMap&
SERVICE=WMS&
VERSION=1.1.1&
WIDTH=1284&
HEIGHT=744&
LAYERS=feature_heatmap&
TRANSPARENT=TRUE&
FORMAT=image%2Fpng&
BBOX=-170.68595869761833,-22.853271028037383,-27.082732891166728,60.356074766355135&
SRS=EPSG:4326&
STYLES=
```

And this is the result shown together with USA map from another WMS

[image]

Comment: which mapserver version are you using?

Comment: The image above was generated by `MapServer version 7.0.7 (MS4W 3.2.3)`.

Comment: Are you using the "mode=map"? I cant get it working without this parameter..

Comment: In my log i see: "msResampleGDALToMap(): no overlap ... no result." when i dont use mode=map in request

Comment: I was testing with a WMS client as you can see from the GetMap request in my answer. By looking at the log message if you use WMS your BBOX is outside your data.

Comment: It's not.. but for some reason, it's not understanding my boundbox as epsg:4326

Comment: i SOLVED! for some reason, i need to use EPSG3857 in the crs parameter!